# Can i unzip my texture on client side in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zip, apk

I'm making an android game and I want to keep my game size as minimal as I can is there any way to add the `Zip` file to `APK` and `unzip` it on the client side so I can reduce my game size?

Also, feel free to share any method that can help me to keep my game size concise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An APK is already a zip file, you won't gain much from it. You can go through assets in your project and tweak compression settings on textures from the editor, possibly limiting resolution